# How to analyse Minikube leakage of storage?

Tags: minikube, skaffold

I have a local cluster with 2 PV

1 For a mysql dump with a 20Gb

1 For Mongo db with around 10Gb

A bunch of different services, mainly images around 400Mb or less, and 1 legacy of 2.1Gb image.

I am running Skaffold + Minikube + VirtualBox

I get the following error from mysql:

```
2020-06-09T12:49:49.854701Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 0, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2020-06-09T12:49:49.854724Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
```

Then I start looking at the current system memory, with this:

```
minikube ssh "free -mh"
```

And I get the following:

```
-------------total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       2.3Gi       2.4Gi       517Mi       3.1Gi       5.3Gi
```

I run the following command:

```
minikube ssh "df -h"
```

And I get the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           7.1G  493M  6.6G   7% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G   26M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1        70G   69G     0 100% /mnt/sda1
/Users          234G  190G   44G  82% /Users
```

I see that `/mnt/sda1` could be the main problem, but I am not able to track down how did that sda1 got filled. How can I see the content /dev/sda1 and the possible guilty process that had filled this device?

I also did the following commands:

`docker image prune` To remove unused images
`docker volume prune` To remove unused volumes

I also run skaffold considering the documuntation with a cleanup:
`skaffoold -f="file-skaffold-config" --no-prune=false --cache-artifacts=false`

`docker rmi -f [IMAGE_ID]` to remove a particular image by ID and see if the removal of this image could eventually free some space in the /dev/sda1

But I cannot see a better situation with my sda1, meaning that `minikube ssh "df -h"` shows exactly the same results as before.

How can I see with minikube / skaffold / docker what is filling up `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: The most traditional tool to help you on investigating what is really consuming the space  is the linux command `du`. [Here](https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-disk-usage-of-files-and-directories/) you can see a few use cases but what I usually do is to run `sudo du -s /dev/sda1/*`, this will show the size of every file and folder inside `/dev/sda1`, than go inside the biggest folder and run `sudo du -s /dev/sda1/example/*` again and so on. This might not be elegant but always works.

Comment: Certainly this is one way, at it also helped me to see with `minikube ssh "sudo du -sh /mnt/sda1/*"` that `/data` which is my pv contains 17 Gb of database, while `/var` contains 46Gb were I have mainly content of docker, space radar got a bit stuck when trying to analyse, this is a good advice thx.

Answer (score 0):

After asking into the github repository for some advice about space consumption in minikube:

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8422

I was pointed out to space radar:

https://github.com/zz85/space-radar/tree/v5.1.0

I will be able to provide further insights and ensure what is producing this disk usage... There is a high chance that the case would be resolved by changing something in the images I am running locally, will update this answer once I know what had happen.

[UPDATE]

At the end, I was able to take a closer look to the problem of minikube from my colleague by evaluating the disk consumption of my machine in regards to his machine.
As pointed out by mWatney in the comments, I did:

```
$ minikube ssh "sudo du -sh /mnt/sda1/*"
17G /mnt/sda1/data
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/hostpath-provisioner
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/hostpath_pv
16K /mnt/sda1/lost+found
46G /mnt/sda1/var
```

But the one from my colleague had:

```
34G /mnt/sda1/data
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/hostpath-provisioner
4.0K    /mnt/sda1/hostpath_pv
16K /mnt/sda1/lost+found
36G /mnt/sda1/var
```

Meaning that he had a problem with the Persistent Volumes, and after doing a fix in his machine in the past he had a back up in the minikube host path PV by mistake, so now it is working fine.